# Buscar valores exactos en un Diccionario Python e imprimirlos

Tags: python, json

Tengo 2 ficheros txt. 1 es un diccionario con termino, valor y tengo otro fichero con un json que simula una lista de tweets.

Tengo que buscar los términos del diccionario en el json y si encuentra el término, que añada el valor a una variable que he asignado antes como 0.

Tengo esta parte de codigo pero no me esta retornando el resultado correcto . Cada linea que lee busca un palabra contenida, pero no la palabra exacta

```
import json

sentimiento=open('Sentimientos.txt')
valores = {}
for linea in sentimiento:
    termino, valor = linea.split("\t")
    valores[termino.lower()] = int(valor)
    

tweets = open ('Tweets.txt')
total = 0

for i, line in enumerate(tweets):
    contenido=json.loads(line)
    if 'text' in contenido: 
        print(" %4d text=%s" % ( i, contenido['text']))
        for sentimiento, valor in valores.items():
            if sentimiento in contenido["text"].lower():
                print("Se ha encontrado {} en el tweet de la linea {} (valor={})"
                  .format(sentimiento, i, valor))
                total += valor
                print("El tweet de la línea {} tiene un valor de {}".format(i, total))` 

> Cita en bloque
```

Comment: Cambia el in de esto: `sentimiento in contenido["text"].lower()` por el operador `==` que justamente sirve (en este caso) para saber si dos cadenas son iguales. `sentimiento == contenido["text"].lower()`

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar cambiar al operador  == no ejecuta nada y no se valida que cantidad de palbras contiene  cada lineas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).